# Get records from compare two table mysql

Tags: mysql

**Table 1**

```
id   |  sub_location  | admin_location 
CUS1 | Valasaravakkam | Tamil Nadu
CUS1 | Alwartirunagar | Chennai
CUS2 | KK Nagar       | Tamil Nadu  
CUS3 | Valasaravakkam | Tamil Nadu  
CUS3 | KK Nagar       | Tamil Nadu  
CUS3 | Alwartirunagar | Chennai
```

**Table 2**

```
id  |  sub_location  | admin_location 
c1  | Porur          | Tamil Nadu
c1  | West Mambalam  | Chennai
c1  | Ashok Nagar    | Tamil Nadu   
c3  | Ramapuram      | Tamil Nadu   
c3  | Nungambakkam   | Tamil Nadu   
c3  | Meenambakkam   | Chennai
```

Get id any one matching sub_location table 1 and table 2 and any one matching admin_location from table 1 and table 2

Comment: Please add your expecting result. Your question is not clear.

Comment: The issue is in the table data. You are asking if both sub_location and admin_location are matched, then return data. But it has no matching rows for sub_location. So it will always  return false and nothing will show up.

Answer (score 0):

Get id of which table table1 or table2?

Comment: get id from table 1

Comment: @chitra : What is your expected result?

Comment: select t1.id from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.sub_location = t2.sub_location or t1.admin_location = t2.admin_location;

Comment: get sub_location from table 1 and find matching sub_location table 2 .if matching any records then get that id

Comment: @chitra : There is no matching `sub_location` from `table1` and `table2`.

Comment: i want matching sub_location and admin_location from both table and get  group by  id

Comment: @chitra : you just add your expecting result. so that we will get a better idea.

Comment: Tamil Nadu or Chennai  in the admin_location and Valasaravakkam or Alwartirunagar in the sub_location from table 1 ... find this the same from the table 2 then fetch that records

Comment: @chitra : And how do you want the output. just add your expected result set please.

Comment: can u understand my question any one?

Comment: grop id (CUS1),sub_location(Valasaravakkam,Alwartirunagar ) and admin_location(Tamil Nadu,Chennai) from table 1 and find table 2 like ,

Comment: find in table 2 (Valasaravakkam or Alwartirunagar )  and admin_location(Tamil Nadu or Chennai)

Comment: for ex : cus1        :          grop id (CUS1),sub_location(Valasaravakkam,Alwartirunagar ) and admin_location(Tamil Nadu,Chennai) from table 1 and find table 2 like , find in table 2 (Valasaravakkam or Alwartirunagar ) and admin_location(Tamil Nadu or Chennai)

Comment: @chitra : still not clear.. You may have to add the expected result or you should explain your problem clearly and the sql query which you have tried so far. Otherwise no one will help you out here. And what is you problem to just adding the expected result.

Comment: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  `sub_location` ) , GROUP_CONCAT(  `admin_location` ) 
FROM  `table 1` 
GROUP BY  `id` 



SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  `sub_location` ) , GROUP_CONCAT(  `admin_location` ) 
FROM  `table 2` 
GROUP BY  `id` 


and then like that find in set table 1 `sub_location` ,table 2 `sub_location` 

table 1 `admin_location` ,table 2 `admin_location`

Comment: why you need group_concat? you only need table1 ids, right?

Comment: yes correct..dont need group_concat..but i need table 1 sub_location campare table 2 sub_location

Comment: i want like that query.. but this is wrong ,, SELECT t1.campaign_id FROM view_stack t1, new_tbl t2 WHERE find in set(t1.sub_locations,t2.sub_locations) and find in set(t1.admin_locations,t2.admin_locations)

Comment: i think you need query like this,

Select id from table1 where find_in_set(sub_location, (select sub_location from table2)) or find_in_set(admin_location, (select admin_location from table2))

but not sure about performance

Comment: SELECT t1.id FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( t1.sub_location, t2.sub_location ) 
AND FIND_IN_SET( t1.admin_location, t2.admin_location ) 
AND t2.id =  'CUS1'
GROUP BY  `id`

Comment: i want like this... this is correct or not ? any one help me